# Int::class.javaPrimitiveType.kotlin reference not equal to Int::class.javaObjectType.kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I think that **CASE 2** should also return true. Is this behavior correct?

```
// CASE 1
Int::class.javaPrimitiveType!!.kotlin == Int::class.javaObjectType.kotlin // true

// CASE 2
Int::class.javaPrimitiveType!!.kotlin === Int::class.javaObjectType.kotlin // false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is correct. `KClass` instances for a primitive type and the corresponding object type are equal (==), however they're created from different `java.lang.Class` instances and since `.java` always returns the original `Class` instance the `KClass` was constructed from, it wouldn't be possible for them to also be identical (===).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: of course it’s hard to tell what the intended behaviour *should be* as nobody of us was involved in making that decision, or writing that code. However, I don’t think that it’s really a requirement that these two objects are in fact the same object; equality is sufficient, reference equality is not required here.